# Unauthorized response when using Passport.js with pub/private keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

Trying to implement the Passport-jwt strategy, I've got it working if I use a string as a 'secret', but I'm struggling to convert it to use a public/private key pair. I've probably made a simple mistake with the keys, but I don't understand what that is.

The login route provides me with a signed token with the pub/priv keys, but is always 'unauthorised' when I try the '/auth/test' route (whereas with the string secret is works)

The code below works, with the non-working code for the pub/priv key code highlighted/commented out.

Any help or comments appreciated!

./controllers/auth.js

```
exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
    (async() => {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOne({ where: {email: req.body.email} });
            if(!user) {
                res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: "Bad Username/Password" });
            }

            const isValid = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.hashedPassword);

            if(isValid) {
                const tokenObject = utils.issueJWT(user);
                res.status(200).json({ success: true, token: tokenObject.token, expiresIn: tokenObject.expires});
            } else {
                res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: "Bad Username/Password" });
            }

        } catch(err) {
            next(err);
        }
    })();
};
```

./config/passport.js

```
...    
const User = require('../models/user');

// ***** Not working
// const pathToKey = path.join(__dirname, '../../../.ssh/', 'jennings.pub');
// const PUB_KEY = fs.readFileSync(pathToKey, 'utf-8');
// *****    

const options = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: 'secret',

    // ***** Not working
    // secretOrKey: PUB_KEY,
    // algorithms: ['RS256']
    // *****
}

function initialize(passport) {
    const authenticateUser = async(jwt_payload, done) => {
        let user;
        try {
            user = await User.findOne({
                where: { id: jwt_payload.sub }
            });
        } catch(e) {
            return done(e, false);
        }

        // No user found
        if(!user) {
            return done(null, false);
        }
        //  User found
        return done(null, user);
    };

    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(options, authenticateUser));
}

module.exports = initialize;
```

./util/utils.js

```
// ***** Not working
// const pathToKey = path.join(__dirname, '../../../.ssh/', 'jennings');
// const PRIV_KEY = fs.readFileSync(pathToKey, 'utf-8');
// *****

exports.issueJWT = (user) => {
    const id = user.id;
    const expiresIn = '1h';

    const payload = {
        sub: id,
        iat: Date.now()
    };

    const signedToken = jwt.sign(payload, 'secret', { expiresIn });

    // ***** Not working
    // const signedToken = jwt.sign(payload, 'secret', { expiresIn,  algorithm: 'RS256'});
    // *****

    return {
        token: "" + signedToken,
        expires: expiresIn
    }
};
```

The test route

```
router.get('/test', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'get in!' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution, based off of two other links:

The first [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012194/asymmetric-keys-with-passport-jwt-verify-always-returns-unauthorized) of an identical problem suggesting that the keys have to be in .pem format (but suggesting using an external library),

and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/706336/how-to-get-a-pem-file-from-ssh-key-pair), which tells you to run `ssh-keygen -f id_rsa.pub -m 'PEM' -e > id_rsa.pem` on the public key to convert it to open-ssl compatible format (the private key is already in .pem format)

That worked for me